# How to I pull inventory report for current cpu /ram / storage configuration for AWS ec2 instance.. need to pull from multiple region multiple account?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

Looking for Python code to pull CPU/RAM/Storage of ec2 instance using list of instance name and arn id and write it to a csv file to create an inventory

Comment: Why do you need to use Terraform for this? Terraform is for provisioning resources, not generating one-off reports.

Comment: Mark is there a service in AWS to pull these parameters as inventory report i

Comment: AWS Config maybe? https://aws.amazon.com/config/ I'm not sure that's going to give you a "report" though. Why not just write some AWS CLI, or Python/Boto3 code to query the list of running EC2 instances?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using python code to query the inventory report for CPU/RAM/STORAGE of ec2 instances